# Using ExecuteSqlCommand and SavesChanges within same transaction with EntityFramework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am chasing an issue with MySql / EF Core where I randomly have an exception thrown saying `Nested transactions are not supported`. This exception does not occur when my system is only used by one user. But when I run my tests in parallel or when I have multiple users, the exception occurs. I looked at all the code and their is nothing that could create nested transactions.

The only piece of codes that scares me so far is something like the following:

```
using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    // Create a few entities and add them to the EF context
    ...

    // Insert the rows: hopefully at this point, my transaction is not commited yet.
    _context.SaveChanges();

    // I then want to update a few rows with a raw sql statement without 
    // having to load the entities in memory.   
    _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE ...");

    // Now that I have inserted and inserted some data, I want to commit all these 
    // changes atomically.
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Is this safe? Am I guaranteed that my SaveChanges and ExecuteSqlCommand will be executed on the same MySqlConnection? I have the feeling that when I call SaveChanges, it closes my connection and puts it back on the connection pool. Then, my ExecuteSqlCommand takes a new connection from the pool (it may be the same one or another one). So my initial connection (the one where I opened the transaction) is put back in the pool and it could be reused by another thread.

This is just a hunch and I am totally not sure if this could cause the problem.

My real question in the end is:

- is it safe to use SaveChanges and ExecuteSqlCommand within a transaction?

Comment: Rather than guessing, use the EF Core [Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging) and you'll see what's going on. But yes, you are guaranteed (or should be - in case there is no implementation bug), otherwise the whole purpose of `BeginTransaction` /  `UseTransaction` makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded from MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore/MySql.Data 6.10.1-beta to 6.10.3-rc and it looks like the problem is gone. Since the problem was random I can't be totally sure that the problem is indeed fixed, but so far so good.

**EDIT:**
3 years later, the problem was never observed anymore.